# Giving away riba in advance

Tags: riba

Can we give away an amount to someone considering it riba but in advance? The riba amount will be credited later to my account but there is someone in need (the person would be informed that it is riba ) that I could give it to right now and later use the actual credited amount for myself?

Not just in terms of riba received in a bank account but also when we receive any riba for investments that we will receive maybe 2-3 years later but could give away the money now instead and use the actual riba for ourselves without considering it riba at that time?

Comment: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9481/is-it-permissible-to-make-a-charitable-donation-in-advance-knowing-that-interest?rq=1  This is similar but just hoping to confirm